# In RealmSwift, is a retain cycle created when each of two objects have a property of the other object?

Tags: swift, realm

For example, with the following objects:

```
import RealmSwift

// Dog model
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var owner: Person?
}

// Person model
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var pet: Dog?
}
```

If you create a dog and a person as follows:

```
let dog = Dog(name: "Pinto")
let guy = Person(name: "Joe")
dog.owner = guy
guy.pet = dog
```

Does this create a retain cycle?

Note: I'm not asking about inverse relationships or LinkingObjects; that's a separate issue that isn't relevant for purposes of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code snippet creates a retain cycle. But if you then add the objects to a Realm file, Realm will break the retain cycle by clearing the object's instance variables.

Managed objects (i.e., objects added to or retrieved from a Realm) don't store any state in their instance variables. Instead, Realm overrides the getters and setters of persisted properties to read or write their values from the underlying Realm file. Because the instance variables are no longer used after adding the object to the Realm, Realm clears them to break any potential cycles.

Comment: So once I write the objects to realm:
`let realm = try! Realm()
 try! realm.write {
    realm.add(dog)
    realm.add(guy)
}`
why does this clear the objects' instance variables?

Comment: Managed objects (i.e., objects added to or retrieved from a Realm) don't store any state in their instance variables. Instead, Realm overrides the getters and setters of persisted properties to read or write their values from the underlying Realm file. Because the instance variables are no longer used after adding the object to the Realm, Realm clears them to break any potential cycles.